# Every simple functions in $L_p(\mathbb{T}) $ is a trigonometric polynomial.

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, hardy-spaces

I know for a finite measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, Simple functions are dense in $L_p(\mu)$. Also it is true that, if we consider normalized Lebesgue measure on the unit circle then trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.

I am new in this area and I cannot relate both the situation. So my question is the following :

Is it true that every simple functions in $L_p(\mathbb{T}) $ is a trigonometric polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not.  Trigonometric polynomials are continuous.  Non-constant simple functions are not.  So no non-constant simple function is a trigonometric polynomial.

Comment: Right. It is true. But my confusion is how it is possible that simple functions are dense in $L_p$ space, whereas its subspace $H_p$ contains no simple functions.

Comment: Analogous to: the irrational numbers are dense in the real numbers, but the rational numbers contain none of them.